# How to replace the "?" using sed

Tags: sed

I would like to know how to replace `?` with `%53` within a string using sed.
I have tried escaping the `?` without success in csh.
   Example: `"string?" | sed 's/\?/%53/g'`.
   I've tried `\\? , [?], [\?], [\\?], \x53`.
Is it even possible, using sed?

Comment: I'm not sure about csh, but usually you need to escape the backslash on input. Have you tried `\\?` yet? (Cannot safely reproduce, since I'm using PowerShell on Windows, but `\\?` works pretty well)

Comment: works for me: `echo "string?" | sed 's/\?/%53/g'`

Comment: is that  your real test, i.e. `echo "string?" | sed ...`? or are you really attempting to process a file created in MSWindows. If a windows file, do `dos2unix file` and try again. Good luck.

Comment: ok, the test was: set InputString = $< $InputString | sed 's/\?/%53/g' thats what didn't work

Answer (score 1):

directly without escpae code between simple quote normaly (test on aix/bash/posix sed and cywin GNU sed) maybe with `-r` option on linux/bash/GNU sed

```
sed 's/?/%53/g'
```